# ModelsState always invalid when using Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

This is how I create my dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NewPageModel.AvailablePageModels, new SelectList(Model.NewPageModel.AvailablePageModels, "Text", "Value"))
```

and this is how my AvailablePageModels looks like

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailablePageModels
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageModelAttribute), true).Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return new SelectListItem { Text = type.Name, Value = type.Name };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when I post my form to the following action my modelstate is always invalid and the error occur on the AvailablePageModel value? Maybe I cannot use the NewPageModel as a parameter this way?

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "NewPageModel")] NewPageModel newPageModel, FormCollection collection)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            // always invalid
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 fields, one for the available options in the drop down list and one for storing the selected value

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewPageModel.SelectedModel, 
new SelectList(Model.NewPageModel.AvailablePageModels, "Text", "Value"))
```